# Problem accessing the DNS

Tags: 14.04, dns

I am using `rtmpdump` to download streaming video. But getting error like this

```
ERROR: Problem accessing the DNS. (addr: __________).
```

if some one can help please reply urgently.

Comment: That is not nearly enough information to try to begin to consider thinking about a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try using another DNS server, like Google's:

**Primary:** `8.8.8.8`
**Secondary:** `8.8.4.4`

Sometimes using a secondary DNS will solve any conflicts/problems that your ISP's default server causes.